# winforms - How to create new menu on button click in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Here is my problem:

I am developing a windows form application.

I am make a simple word process, and im already make open, save and save as menu.

This is my code:

```
 private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
            if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                rtbDocument.LoadFile(openFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

                saveFileDialog.FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(saveFileDialog.FileName == "")
            {
                saveFileDialog.FileName = "";
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
                if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    rtbDocument.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                rtbDocument.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
            }
        }

        private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            string filename = "";

            // To filter files from SaveFileDialog
            saveDlg.Filter = "Rich Text File (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
            /*saveDlg.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";*/
            /*saveDlg.FilterIndex = 1;*/
            saveDlg.Title = "Save the contents";

            DialogResult retval = saveDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (retval == DialogResult.OK)
                filename = saveDlg.FileName;
            else
                return;

            /*RichTextBoxStreamType stream_type;
            if (saveDlg.FilterIndex == 2)
                stream_type = RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText;
            else
                stream_type = RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText;*/

            rtbDocument.SaveFile(filename);
            MessageBox.Show("File Saved");
        }
```

Im already trying this code:

```
 private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbDocument.Text = "";
        }
```

But this code only make rich textbox empty.

The problem is i want when new menu button is clicked the rich textbox will be empty as well as when doing Save (not Save As) it will reopen a dialog box to give it a name and choose a location file storage.

Can anyone help in this, and give me some sample code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: So you want to do exactly the same as what now happens with "save" but additionally empty the textbox? Then put the code you currently have in the ItemClick Event for "save" into a method and call that method from both ItemClick EventHandler.

Comment: At best let the method return (with a bool) if a save has actually been done and the user has not cancelled the SaveDialog if he got to see that one and only empty the textbox if save has happened. It would be quite angering if you empty the textbox but the user has cancelled saving here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just also set `saveFileDialog.FileName` back to a blank string as that is what you check for in the save routine:

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtbDocument.Text = "";
    saveFileDialog.FileName = "";
}
```